# Any way to run events after clicking stop debugging button ? c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

It is possible to capture on close or on error and run the code that we want.

However still i am at the developing phase and will be a lot more time, i am running application as debugging mode (clicking F5 button)

And also terminating application with stop debugging (shift F5)

When i terminate application with stop debugging the on close events are not firing (the ones that fire when you close application with clicking X mark on right top)

So are there any way to make application run on stop debugging button click ?

Here below my on close function - inside MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Closing += new CancelEventHandler(CloseCrashHandlers.CloseHander);
```

Thank you very much for answers

Visual Studio 2013 V3

Comment: Can you not just close the window instead of terminating debugging? allowing code to continue after terminating debugging kinda defeats the purpose of terminating debugging, just close your app, it will fire all your events then will stop debugging

Comment: Clicking "close" is not always an option.  For example, asp.net web apps have no "close" button; their session remains active after closing a web browser window.  If it's running in IIS Express, you can right click it and choose "stop", which will fire Session_End and CurrentDomain_DomainUnload events (but not CurrentDomain_ProcessExit).  I wish there was a way to intercept the "stop debugging" event or override its behavior, because it currently seems to abruptly stop the process without allowing any clean up code to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to execute some custom code (or to 'make an application run' as you state in your question) when you hit the shift+F5 combination to stop debugging an application running under debugger is to create a Visual Studio extension (or addin) that hooks next visual studio extensibility event:

```
EnvDTE.DebuggerEvents _dteDebuggerEvents;

_dteDebuggerEvents = VsObject.DTE.Events.DebuggerEvents;

_dteDebuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode += _dteDebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignMode;
_dteDebuggerEvents.OnContextChanged += _dteDebuggerEvents_OnContextChanged;


void _dteDebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignMode(dbgEventReason Reason)
{
   switch (Reason)
   {
       case dbgEventReason.dbgEventReasonStopDebugging:
             // do whatever you need here
       break;
   }
}
```

Note: You won't be able to execute any code from your own running app using above handler.

Comment: ty basically it is impossible :D

Comment: Just adding here a way how to get the VsObject:
`var VsObject = (EnvDTE.DTE)await GetServiceAsync(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));` and then it is: 
`_dteDebuggerEvents = VsObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;`